# When requestLocationUpdates call?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am trying to call requestLocationUpdates using above:

```
locationUpdateRequester.requestLocationUpdates(900000, 75, criteria, locationListenerPendingIntent);
```

When it call requestLocationUpdates again after approx 15 min and 75 meter distance cover by device?

Comment: Can you please repeat your question again?

Comment: When requestLocationUpdates call?if i pass 15min time and 75 meter distance to the method.Weather it call after every 15min and 75 meter or any of them satisfied?

Comment: yaa, it is invoked if any of both is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks at every 15 min interval, the change in distance. 
Whenever the distance increases above 75 meter, onLocationChanged() is invoked.